# Scale website to fill vertical viewport

Tags: css, html, mobile, meta

I've got a website which is 940x630 Pixels in size.
Now the customer wishes that the website should fit on *all* devices, even if it means to scale the whole site down.
The problem is, I get it to scale to the width of the device, but there's still some vertical scrolling, if the content doesn't fit.
It seems that every viewport attribute height=device-height or height=640 is ignored (at least on my Galaxy SII)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Not a realistic expectation from the client imo. Scaling the width is the norm but vertical scrolling is expected.

Comment: What is wrong with vertical scrolling? Btw how can there be vertical scrolling if its bigger width to lower height? Or u are talking about landscape position of mobile device? Would be also nice if u show us some html/css code.

Comment: i agree that it isn't a realistic expectation. the problem is that the client saw the site on an ipad where it scaled properly (because of the screen ratio) and on smartphones in landscape mode it doesn't.

Comment: try this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some kind of mobile site/bootstrap. If you look at a site on desktop and then their mobile option you will notice that they have had to remove and shift things around. This is due to mobile devices not having enough space to display everything horizontally and forcing them into the vertical that you are talking about. As stated above by @Andrew, the css-tricks.com site is very useful. You can probably keep everything the same for tablets and remove/redo only some elements for cell phones.